# Create Azure Api App from Swagger meta data

Tags: api, azure, swagger, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I have created some APIs in API management layer, which are essentially proxies between the calling client and an underlying web api.

I did this by importing the swagger file of the underlying API, and then adding the newly created API to a Product, repeating this for each separate proxy that I needed. This means then that the underlying API could be called but not without the subscriber key of the product that the newly created API was attached to.

[image]

Is it possible to do something similar with API apps, i.e. creating API apps  using just the swagger file from the underlying API in the azure portal, that act as proxies between the calling client and an underlying web api (as below)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind expanding on why do you need to have API Apps acting as proxies?

I am not aware of such capability for API Apps specifically. There are Swagger-based code generation tools available, for example on http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/. So perhaps you will be able to find something that would work for you.